# Two Monitor in one VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I'm trying to create a virtual machine(OS = Windows 7) with 2 displays on vSphere. VM has VMware Tools. I go to

`Edit Virtual Machine Settings > Video Card > Maximum Number of Displays [2].`

When I click ok. The configuration returns to Maximum number of displays = 1. what should I do to keep the change?

Comment: What OS is the VM running: Linux or Windows? Have you installed VMware Tools in the VM?

Comment: That might be by design as vSphere is not geared towards running desktop configurations. Good chance the setting is left there for VMware Workstation compatibility/interoperability.

Comment: @user48838 - I couldn't disagree more, vSphere is more than capable of running oceans of desktops, in fact with shared memory it's easier than many other systems and v4 introduced support for multiple monitors.
@Eduardo - have you increased the amount of video memory you've assigned to your VM? You can also set it to 'auto' too.

Comment: @chopper3 I have tried increasing the amount of video memory and tried 'auto' too. Nothing worked. And I really need this VM with 2 monitors.

Answer (score 8):

### -- Who would encounter this problem --

- Anyone who are using "bare-metal" hypervisor such as vSphere ESXi which installs directly onto machine with no OS require.

### -- Why this problem exists --

- This is the strategy that VMware has been taken in order to separate the feature giving for VM access through:

  - vSphere Client's "Guest Console" for administration purpose (only single monitor), 
    VS.,
  - VMware View for end user usage (support multiple monitors)
- In fact not only multiple monitors, there are also lots of other features you see in Workstation, Player, ESX are locked away in vSphere Client.

### -- Our goal --

- Assuming vSphere Client is installed on a remote machine with dual monitors (each 1600x1200)
- The following solution will make the vSphere Client's "Guest Console" to see a single monitor of one resolution (say 3000x1000),  which is slightly less than the sum of 2 monitors, because we have to take into the account of the window of the "Guest Console".
- It took me weeks to figure this out.

### -- Solution --

1. Make sure your "Guest Console" has the maximum setting for your video memory and resolution

   - Edit Virtual Machine Settings > on the top right corner make sure "Hardware version 7" is use
   - Edit Virtual Machine Settings > Hardware > Video Card > Memory required for displays > Enter total video RAM > 128
   - Edit Virtual Machine Settings > Options > General > Configuration Parameters... > click "Add Row" button to add the following parameters:

     - svga.autodetect => false
     - svga.maxHeight => 1200
     - svga.maxWidth => 3200
2. Download the "latest VMware Tools" (e.g. "VMware-tools-windows-8.3.7-381511.iso") into you remote machine from:

   - http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/latest/windows/x86_64/index.html
3. Install the "latest VMware Tools" into your Windows 7 in your "Guest Console"

   - first uninstall the "old/existing VMware Tools" in your Windows 7
   - in the "Guest Console" there is a "CD/DVD" button, click on it
   - select "Connect to ISO image on local disk"
   - select the "VMware-tools-windows-8.3.7-381511.iso" you have downloaded in step 2
   - begin install the VMware Tools to the Windows 7
   - upon completion restart your Windows 7
4. Enable 2 displays/monitors in one VM

   - in the Windows 7, start the dos prompt
   - type in 'cd C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools', press 'enter'
   - type in 'VMwareResolutionSet.exe 0 1 , 0 0 3000 1000' (you may replace the value 3000 and 1000 to a value less than the sum of your 2 displays/monitors' resolution), press 'enter'
   - now you will see your new screen resolution to 3000x1000
5. To make the Windows 7's new screen resolution fit the "Guest Console"

   - goto the menu of the "Guest Console"
   - click on "View" > "Fit Window Now"
   - in some case you can freely change your "Guest Console" and click on "Fit Guest Now", this will change your Windows 7 resolution to fit the "Guest Console" window

Comment: do you have a reference for the command line of vmwareresolutionset.exe, by any chance?